Wix Installer failing with Hash mismatch error
My installer failed with below log errors.

e000: Error 0x80091007: Hash mismatch for path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{0120503F-72AF-4880-B381-B9F1418EB786}v1.0.0.0\IISInstallation, expected: 8AA50D1AA48711BDAF934D5DAD6674FD56670F79, actual: 35A87DA0B621B40181ECD2A1CCBDAA8B9C660102


[5544:4D70][2024-12-17T02:01:09]e000: Error 0x80091007: Failed to verify hash of payload: IISWebServerRole


[5544:4D70][2024-12-17T02:01:09]e310: Failed to verify payload: IISWebServerRole at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{0120503F-72AF-4880-B381-B9F1418EB786}v1.0.0.0\IISInstallation, error: 0x80091007. Deleting file.


[5544:4D70][2024-12-17T02:01:09]e000: Error 0x80070002: Failed to find payload: IISWebServerRole in working path: C:\Windows\Temp{E17C1111-28D5-427F-AF65-6690961B0ACB}\IISWebServerRole and unverified path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache.unverified\IISWebServerRole


[5544:4D70][2024-12-17T02:01:09]e000: Error 0x80070002: Failed to cache payload: IISWebServerRole
[0E30:19C0][2024-12-17T02:01:09]e314: Failed to cache payload: IISWebServerRole from working path: C:\Windows\Temp{E17C1111-28D5-427F-AF65-6690961B0ACB}\IISWebServerRole, error: 0x80070002.
[0E30:19C0][2024-12-17T02:01:09]e349: Application requested retry of payload: IISWebServerRole, encountered error: 0x80070002. Retrying...

And here is my bundle code
        <Chain>
            <MsiPackage Id="IISWebServerRole" Name="IISInstallation" 
            ForcePerMachine="yes" SourceFile="IISFeature\bin\x64\Release\IISFeature.msi" Visible="no" 
            LogPathVariable="LogIISWebServerRole"
            DisplayInternalUI="no" Vital="no" Permanent="yes">
                     <MsiProperty Name="INSTALLFOLDER" Value="[InstallFolder]" />     
            </MsiPackage>
            <ExePackage Id="DotNetSDK6" PerMachine="yes" SourceFile="prerequisite\dotnet-sdk-6.0.401-win-x64.exe" RepairCommand="/quiet /repair /norestart" InstallCommand="/quiet /norestart" Vital="no" Permanent="yes" LogPathVariable="LogDotNetSDK6Bundle"></ExePackage>
            <ExePackage Id="DotNetCoreHostingBundle" PerMachine="yes" SourceFile="dotnet8\dotnet-hosting-8.0.10-win.exe" RepairCommand="/quiet /repair /norestart" InstallCommand="/quiet /norestart" Vital="no" Permanent="yes" LogPathVariable="LogDotNetCoreHostingBundle"></ExePackage>
            <ExePackage Id="DotNet8Runtime" PerMachine="yes" SourceFile="prerequisite\dotnet-runtime-8.0.8-win-x86.exe" RepairCommand="/quiet /repair" DetectCondition="(Dotnet8RuntimeFound ~= &quot;True&quot;)" InstallCommand="/quiet /restart" Vital="no" Permanent="yes" LogPathVariable="LogDotNet8Runtime"></ExePackage>
            <ExePackage Id="WindowsDesktopDotNet8Runtime" PerMachine="yes" SourceFile="dotnet8\windowsdesktop-runtime-8.0.10-win-x64.exe" RepairCommand="/quiet /repair" DetectCondition="(WindowsDesktopDotNet8RuntimeFound ~= &quot;True&quot;)" InstallCommand="/quiet /restart" Vital="no" Permanent="yes" LogPathVariable="LogWindowsDesktopDotNet8Runtime"></ExePackage>
            
...
</Chain>

Why might it be failing?
